# Type error: 'float object not callable'

Tags: python

why would a simple `time.sleep(1)` statement cause a :

```
Type error : 'float' object not callable?
```

Code is as follows:

```
try:
    while True
        time.sleep(10)
        current_state = GPIO.input(pir_sensor)
        if current_state ==1:
            print "PIR Activated"
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Please add Full Trackback here !

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Not this, Full error track back and it to your question with edit it.

Comment: File "home/pi/security1.py" line 35, in <module>..time.sleep(10) >>TypeError: 'float' object is not callable>>

Comment: Please add it to your question, not in the comments. And  please add the whole code before this part. Could you have somewhere before something like `time.sleep = <some float >`?

Comment: That does not seem to be your full code-listing (i.e. no import of `time`)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be because of the `time.sleep(10)`
On the second line the while loop is missing a colon:

```
try:
    while True: # <-- Added colon here
        time.sleep(10)
        current_state = GPIO.input(pir_sensor)
        if current_state == 1:
            print "PIR Activated"
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Thanks but the colon is used in the actual code. I missed it when typing the question.

Comment: It is a `Syntax error` , nothing to do with `TypeError`